# Android Gps Routing system

Tags: android, routes, gps, location

I'm developing an android application that would locate the user(assuming that the user is on the road) and  the app will create the shortest route for the user to take to be able to go to the users chosen destination. Locating the user isn't the question since there's an API for that here:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

so here's the catch. The roads ,intersections and their distances can be mapped or declared via variables in the code but my problem is that the GPS APIs i found so far would only return a longitude and latitude and not the road names or the graphs that can be used for mapping the shortest path. I need help as to how i can create the shortest route with the given Android GPS resources we have now.

Assuming: 3G or wifi connection is always available

Comment: Google :) Try searching their maps library

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code (licensed under Apache 2.0) in our open-source OpenTripPlanner for Android app:
https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/OpenTripPlanner-for-Android/wiki

See the wiki for a full summary of the app, but here's a short description:

OTP for Android uses the open-source [OpenTripPlanner server instances](https://github.com/openplans/OpenTripPlanner/wiki/) to plan multimodal routes (bus, bike, and walk) via calls to the [OTP Server REST API](http://www.opentripplanner.org/apidoc/).  Once the trip plan is retrieved from the server, it is shown to the user.

OTP uses [OpenStreetMap data](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) for road/sidewalk/bike lane information, and [General Transit Feed Specification](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference) data for transit information.