# Implementing navigation in Android

Tags: android, android-mapview

I want to implement a navigation functionality in my application in android so that the user can set destination and the application guide him through the way. It's exactly like the Navigation app in Android except I need to add more information during the navigation along his travel way (like our company branches locations near him).

So, Can I build this functionality over the locally installed navigation application ?
If not, can I make the same functionality in my app using the MapViews and is there some APIs available for that?

If not, what will be the best way to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I have the same implementation in my application. can you please help me to kick this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320714/1159056) answer, it will surely answer your question!

**short answer:** You can use [OpenTripPlanner for Android](https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/OpenTripPlanner-for-Android/wiki) to get the routing through their REST API.

Answer (score 1):

You can't build information on top of the android navigation app. You can make your own navigation app but that will be an awful lot of work.